# Canvas Scaler issues

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Screen-Space Camera as a render mode on canvas but the Textmeshpro text is looking blurry. I think it might be due to canvas scaler setting.
Following is the result I am getting in unity and Canvas settings. 
[image: Result]

[image: Canvas setting]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thing might be the `Reference Resolution`. Can you show us also the settings for `TextMeshPro`?

Comment: Added, but other UI elements also look blurry

Answer (score 0):

After playing with different settings finally, I solved it after disabling Allow HDR on camera setting.